# How to select the first record from group?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a list/array of records, and I'm using `explode` to extract data from the list.  I'd like to pick the first record from the exploded result, using Spark SQL in Java.

```
Dataset<Row> ds= ds.select(
  json.col("*"), 
  explode(json.col("records.record.newrecord")).as("newrecord"));
ds= ds.select(ds.col("EVENT_SEQ"), ds.col("newrecord").apply("event").as("EVENTTYPE"));
```

Current Data:

```
|           EVENT_SEQ|EVENTTYPE|
+--------------------+---------+
|5a694d77-bc65-4bf...|        0|
|5a694d77-bc65-4bf...|        0|
+--------------------+---------+
```

Requirements:

```
|           EVENT_SEQ|EVENTTYPE|
+--------------------+---------+
|5a694d77-bc65-4bf...|        0|
+--------------------+---------+
```

I have seen documentation that suggests `Cloumn.apply` for this purpose, but I haven't found enough help to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's certainly `groupBy` operator with `first` function.

```
val ds = Seq(
  ("5a694d77-bc65-4bf...", 0),
  ("5a694d77-bc65-4bf...", 0)
).toDF("EVENT_SEQ", "EVENTTYPE")
scala> ds.show
+--------------------+---------+
|           EVENT_SEQ|EVENTTYPE|
+--------------------+---------+
|5a694d77-bc65-4bf...|        0|
|5a694d77-bc65-4bf...|        0|
+--------------------+---------+

scala> ds.groupBy("EVENT_SEQ").agg(first("EVENTTYPE")).show
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|           EVENT_SEQ|first(EVENTTYPE, false)|
+--------------------+-----------------------+
|5a694d77-bc65-4bf...|                      0|
+--------------------+-----------------------+
```